# Conversion from vertrigoServ 2.22 to xampp server 3.2.1

Tags: javascript, php, xampp, localhost

I was using following tag (PHP embedded in HTML) in an old version of localhost (vertrigoServ 2.22):

```
<body onLoad="loadPageContents('<?php echo $data; ?>', '<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>', '<?php echo $city_id; ?>');">
```

It was working perfect.

Then I moved to latest version of localhost (xampp server 3.2.1)

But the function `loadPageContents()` is not executing at all.

Please give me some solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<body onLoad="loadPageContents(<?php echo "'$data', '$_SESSION[id]', '$city_id'"; ?>);">
```